# How to connect opencart with mssql server

Tags: sql-server, opencart

Is there any chance of connecting opencart with mssql? Have anyone tried? If so what is the procedure of doing that?

[image]

Comment: This is difficulty which i faced in project, why the people gave negative point for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not be a big problem, You only need to do:

- create `/system/database/mssql.php` class - the class should have the same methods, properties and functionality as e.g. the `mysql.php` one
- rewrite **all of the model classes method's queries** to meet the `MS SQL` / `T-SQL` SQL syntax
- in both config files (`/config.php` and `/admin/config.php`) set the proper `DB_DRIVER` - `mssql`

I am supposing You have the OpenCart database created already due to the `/install/opencart.sql` file.

I guess nothing more should be done.

Anyway, what is the reason for switching to MS SQL?

**EDIT**: In `/system/database/` there is this `mmsql.php` file which actually contains the `MSSQL` class thus this do not have to be implemented, just **renamed** to `mssql.php` file.

Comment: i tried, but its not working. it keep on showing undefined function mssql_connect. i have added dll named php_pdo_mssql and php_mssql even though it shows same error.

Comment: The problem lies elsewhere. What server are You using? Are You sure the server allows You to connect to MSSQL server? I had a similar problem with Apache not compiled for Oracle (oci extension) and I had to reinstall. Create a simple PHP file within the web root trying to connect to MSSQL and retrieve some data. If You succeed outside the OpenCart then within it it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: im using apache server... it works in codeigniter but i need to work in opencart...

Comment: Supposing Your codeigniter is running on the same server and with the same PHP (and same PHP configuration) as the OpenCart installation and still You are receiving the `undefined function mssql_connect` error I'd recommend checking the OC's `mssql.php` class that it uses the right functions for `MSSQL`...

Comment: i din't us php_mssql.dll, instead of that 1'm using php_sqlsrv.dll. because php_mssql.dll was showing the error which i added with the question. Note: i'm using xampp 1.8 (i.e) php 5.4.*.