# How to connect an opencart application to an ms sql server database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, opencart

I am trying to make an open cart application using php, and I want to connect it a sql server. The database is not mysql database. I have the following error: `Call to undefined function DB\mssql_connect()`. I set my config file like that:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/restaurant/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://localhost/restaurant/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost/restaurant/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://localhost/restaurant/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', 'E:/my work/wamp/www/restaurant/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mssql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'AndlusMarket');
define('DB_PORT', '1433');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

I searched a lot for a solution, but many people said it is too difficult. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: What version of PHP? `mssql_*` functions have been removed from PHP 7. You should probably use [`sqlsrv_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) for connecting to a SQL Server instead

Comment: php 5.1.12 @ImClarky that's the version i'm using

Comment: Have a Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558056/how-to-connect-opencart-with-mssql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should update your question and be specific for the opencart version. No problem all right so in newer version there is built in class named mpdo. so you need to just

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mpdo');
try {
    $this->connection = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . $hostname . ";port=" . $port . ";dbname=" . $database, $username, $password, array(\PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \Exception('Failed to connect to database. Reason: \'' . $e->getMessage() . '\'');
}

$this->connection->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$this->connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$this->connection->exec("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8");
$this->connection->exec("SET SQL_MODE = ''");
```

Replace it with

```
try {
    $this->connection = new \PDO("sqlsrv:Server=" . $hostname . ";port=" . $port . ";Database=" . $database, $username, $password);
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \Exception('Failed to connect to database. Reason: \'' . $e->getMessage() . '\'');
}
$this->connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Comment: that's nice it gave me exception failed to connect to database

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PDO to connect your OpenCart

I have created PDO class for mysql you can download from [OpenCart PDO](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9693-PHP-OpenCart-database-access-driver-for-MySQL-with-PDO.html#view_files/files/74453)

you need to put this class in

```
{your opencart folder} > system >database > pdo.php
```

create class file name with pdo.php

Just replace class name with DBpdo

Just replace the string in class

```
$this->params->connstr = "sqlsrv:Server={$host};dbname={$name};charset={$charset}";
```

and you need to change in your config.php

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'PDO');
```

you could replace

```
$this->dbh->exec($this->options['PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND']);
```

with

```
$this->dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Comment: Could not load database driver PDO! it gives me that error ?

Comment: you need to give class name DBpdo
and
define('DB_DRIVER', 'pdo');

Comment: what do u mean by u need to give class name DBpdo ?

Comment: yes, you need to update class name with DBpdo in db.php it include with DB prefix

Comment: it gives me that error :  Class 'DBpdo' not found in index

Comment: Have you created class file name with "pdo" and class name with "Dbpdo" right?

Comment: it gives me the following error : Error: Could not load database driver PDO! ?

Comment: Have you download class file ?
or use lower case in config file
define('DB_DRIVER', 'pdo');

Comment: just put lower case in config.php define('DB_DRIVER', 'pdo');

Comment: file name case is lower as same as in config.php

Comment: it gives me a new error :  Cannot redeclare class pdo

Comment: I repeat procedure : 

1) create class file name pdo.php 

2) download class file OC_PDO.php from phpclasses.org

3) replace class name from OC_PDO to pdo mark words class name not file name pls

4) assign db driver name as pdo in config.php 
define('DB_DRIVER', 'pdo');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', '{your host name}');
define('DB_USERNAME', '{user name}');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '{password}');
define('DB_DATABASE', '{database name}');
define('DB_PREFIX', '{prefix}');

Comment: Undefined class constant 'DB\PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT' in db.php line 9 , that's a new error

Comment: Just comment out 'PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE' => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT in pdo.php

Comment: Class 'DB\stdClass' not found , that's the error right now , i'm using php 5.5.2 can it be the problem ?

Comment: No its not an issue. can you tell me opencart version

Comment: 2.2.0 compiled  that's the version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110963/discussion-between-mohamed-elbiheiry-and-pranav-bhatt).